# How to validate date entry on android?

Tags: android, validation, date

On Android, the date displays as mm/dd/yyyy; which would be fine, but it doesn't validate. I assume android actually sends the date in a different format than it displays. I can't figure out what the format is. If I knew I think could validate it. Currently the input can be m(m)-d(d)-yyyy which the field stipulates, but I need to accept android datepicker format too, so it could also accept m(m)/d(d)/yyyy

Here's the validation function from my validator class

```
     function isInvalidDate($field, $msg) {
        $value = $this->getValue($field);
        $valueDate = str_replace("/","-",$value);
        $value_arr = explode('-', $valueDate);
        if (checkdate($value_arr[0], $value_arr[1], $value_arr[2])) {
            return true;
        } else {
            $this->addError($field, $value, $msg);
            return false;
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are doing server/client communication, the client is an Android app.
The server accept the posted data from client, you can define the date format the server can receive by yourself.

Before the client post your data to the server, the client (Android app) should convert the date format to the format the server accepted.

E.g, the server only accept the date format `mm/dd/yyyy`, before Android app send data to the server, it should format the result to `mm/dd/yyyy` after date set in `DatePickerDialog`.

```
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, new OnDateSetListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                int dayOfMonth) {
            String dateString = String.format("%02d", monthOfYear) + "/" +
                String.format("%02d", dayOfMonth) + "/" + year;
            // TODO: send dateString to the server
        }
    }, calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    datePickerDialog.show();
```

Comment: Alijandro, this may be something I don't understand about php. I thought user input should be validated before any reformatting is performed. Please comment.

Comment: this looks like javascript, which I haven't learned. Can I plug this script in as is or do I need to modify certain elements? Which ones?

Answer (score -1):

**Perfect marriage date of year BallVivah or not**
*please used this code*

```
public static int getPerfectMarriageOfYear(int Byear, int Bmonth, int Bdate, int Myear, int Mmonth, int Mdate) {

    Calendar dobCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar marriageCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    dobCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, Byear);
    dobCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, Bmonth);
    dobCalendar.set(Calendar.DATE, Bdate);

    marriageCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, Myear);
    marriageCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, Mmonth);
    marriageCalendar.set(Calendar.DATE, Mdate);

    int ageInteger = 0;

    ageInteger = marriageCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR) - dobCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);

    if (marriageCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) == dobCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)) {

        if (marriageCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) < dobCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)) {

            ageInteger = ageInteger - 1;
        }

    } else if (marriageCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) < dobCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)) {

        ageInteger = ageInteger - 1;

    }

    return ageInteger;
}
```

Comment: This seems completely unrelated to the question